# forming structure to read bson object with composite key

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I have an aggregation query (MongoDB, using mgo library), which groups the documents by a composite key. I want to add the result of this aggregation to another collection (I have use out stage of aggregation The result of this aggregation, which shows correct results but I cannot use out since it overwrites records every time the query is run).

snippet of group stage: basically I am grouping by a key which is composite, of a,b and c.

```
    "$group": bson.M{
        "_id": bson.M{
            "a": "$a",
            "b": "$b",
            "c": "$c",
        },
     x: "x",
     y: "y" ..etc
```

I have tested the aggregation / grouping etc with out stage and it gives expected result.

To add to another collection, I want to read each bson object as a struct and then insert into another collection. The problem is  how to define the object for the composite key.

For example:

```
type test struct {
Id string `bson:"_id"` <---- how to define composite key that I want to use as key in new collection
X string `bson:x`
Y string `bson:y`
}
```

I hope my question is clear, I can add more information if required to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, answering to help if someone runs into the same.

You can created another struct for composite key.

```
type key struct {
    a string 
    b string 
    c int 
}

type test struct {
Id key `bson:"_id"` <---- how to define composite key that I want to use as key in new collection
X string `bson:x`
Y string `bson:y`
}
```